# Position subviews on superview based on subview count

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, alignment

Subviews need to be placed from the center of super view based on subview count.
If subview count is odd, the middle view will be center to the super view and remaining will be placed with respect to it with item spacing.
[image]

If subview count is even, then subviews are to be placed with offset.
[image]

Is there any generic solution to solve this without too many conditions and calculations using autolayout?

All subviews are of same size

Comment: You could introduce another uiview to contain all these subviews, then simply center that view within the initial superview.

Comment: Why not use a UICollectionView and adjust the item size to accommodate the subviews? If you feel that is overkill, you could use a stack view to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1: UIStackView**

[image: 4 subviews]

```
    let totalSubviews = 4
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.axis = .Horizontal
    stackView.distribution = .EqualSpacing
    stackView.alignment = .Center
    stackView.spacing = 10
    stackView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).active = true
    stackView.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).active = true
    stackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    for _ in 0 ..< totalSubviews {
        let subview = UIView()
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(subview)
        subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        subview.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        subview.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50).active = true
        subview.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50).active = true
    }
```

**Solution 2: AutoLayout**

You can do this generically using AutoLayout.

`totalSubviews = 4`

[image: 4 subviews]

`totalSubviews = 5`

[image: 5 subviews]

**Code**

```
    let totalSubviews = 4
    let spacing = CGFloat(20)
    var subviews = [UIView]()

    var previousSubview: UIView?
    for i in 0 ..< totalSubviews {
        let subview = UIView()
        subviews.append(subview)
        view.addSubview(subview)
        subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        subview.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: spacing))

        if i == 0 {
            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: spacing))
        }
        else if i < totalSubviews {
            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: previousSubview, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: spacing))
        }
        if i == totalSubviews - 1 {
            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: -spacing))
        }

        if i != 0 {
            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: previousSubview!, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        }


        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: 100))

        previousSubview = subview
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to take 1 more view inside main view which will include your odd or even number of `subviews`. Then you need to set Equal width and Equal height constraints between them. So as per your number of `subviews` and screen size, they all will automatically be positioned.